# Resize image to parent div? Using parent div only?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I have an image inside a div. image should resize itself base on this div’s dimensions (without messing up the ratio)

```
<div class="w-50">
  <img src="" class="w-full h-full image-cover">
</div>
```

However I can only change the div class and not the image tag class. So things like: max-h-full max-w-full object-contain haven’t been working.Any work arounds?

Comment: I'm assuming the unclosed class attribute and the unicode quotes weren't from your raw code?

Comment: Do you want the whole image to be totally in view (a contain sort of setting) or do you want it to totally cover the parent div (a cover type setting - where either top and bottom or the sides are cropped as needed depending on the relative aspect ratios of div and original image)?

Comment: @A Haworth contain sort of setting

Comment: @Mcaden yes typo

Comment: What are the div's dimensions - I can see the w-50 but does that imply a height?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
.w-50 img { width:100%;}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Comment: i don't understand how this needs more explanation,  can't be more simple. and i don't want to make it complicated @novonimo

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
.w-50{
width:100%
or
margin:
}
```

Comment: when you add an answer you put the code in the proper format, you can use 4 spaces or hover the code and do ctrl+k to indent properly.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improve the long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer.